# How can I add a tag between items in an ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

I have this object of data and I need to add a simple  tag after the second card from "cards" list. How can I do this in Angular?

```js
cards = [
    { id: '1', title: 'Card1', pages: 5 },
    { id: '2', title: 'Card2', pages: 2 },
    { id: '3', title: 'Card3', pages: 6 },
    { id: '4', title: 'Card4', pages: 12 },
    { id: '5', title: 'Card5', pages: 7 }
]
```

```html
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <div class="left">
        <a class="title" target="_blank">
            {{card.title}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a class="date" target="_blank">
                <small>{{card.pages}}</small>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: What do you mean by tag ? anchor tag etc.

Comment: Where should the tag be rendered?

Comment: I mean by tag , an Html <h1> tag, and it should rendering after a second Card from a cards list

Answer (score 1):

The `ngFor` structural directive provides [local variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) that can be used to find your position in the loop.

You're looking for this one:

> `index: number`: The index of the current item in the iterable.

Access the index by adding an alias to the directive (here I've used `i`) then referencing the alias inside the loop. I've used the [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) structural directive to only render the `h1` tag if the current index is 1 (the second card since indices start at 0).

```html
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cards; index as i">
    <div class="left">
        <a class="title" target="_blank">
            {{card.title}}
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a class="date" target="_blank">
                <small>{{card.pages}}</small>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1 *ngIf="i == 1">Here's your tag.</h1>
</mat-card>
```

---

If you need the tag to be outside of the card, you'll need to move the `ngFor` to a [container](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container) and put the card and the `h1` tag inside the container:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards; index as i">
    <mat-card>
        <div class="left">
            <a class="title" target="_blank">
                {{card.title}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <a class="date" target="_blank">
                    <small>{{card.pages}}</small>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
    <h1 *ngIf="i == 1">Here's your tag. (It's outside the card now).</h1>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thank
What if I need to render different content in h1 tag ?
Like this 
In first tag to render this content "First exemple"
in second tag other content ...

Comment: Use the same trick - put the different items in the `h1` tag and use `ngIf` on each one of them to only render when `i` is some value you care about.